# Running a Excel Macro in Linux Server

Tags: linux, excel, vba

I have a website currently running and I have written some Microsoft excel macros. Is there any possible way I can run the macro on my website which runs on Linux server?

I made some research and it says that macros are not supported in Linux server. Is there a way to get around these and make the macros interact with my website site code (HTML, PHP)?

I am thinking of recoding the VBA codes in PHP language directly on the website, but that would be a lot of work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the VBA code doing? IMO when you have MS Excel workbook with VBA macros and you need the website to use these VBA macros then one possibility would be a web server which can host MS Excel and this is some Windows server with IIS. So move the website from Linux to Windows, from Apache? to IIS and then install MS Excel on that windows server and there would be a possibility that your application which runs now on IIS can use your VBA code. MS Excel is not supported by Linux so you can't have MS Excel running on your Linux server.

Comment: while researching I came across wineserver...would installing it make any difference?

Comment: you can rewrite your macros to VBScripts for independent run (should be not so hard). And run it over Wine. [some example](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=39641)

Comment: sorry..contacted by server admin...they said wine is not supported..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel does not run on Linux. There are alternatives that run on Linux (Open Office, StarOffice) which may or may not have their own version of macros but it won't be VBA.

Comment: wt would be ur suggestion for me?